# Get current projectile root path in elisp

Tags: emacs, path, projectile

Is there any way to get the current projectile root path in elisp.

Something similar to the command `eproject-root` in `eproject.`

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is! The function is called `projectile-project-root`. You can see an example use [here](https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el/blob/5649028ea0c049cb7dfa2105285dee9c00d189fb/virtualenvwrapper.el#L93-L102) in my virtualenvwrapper.el project.

Comment: I have a variable named this, which is nil

Answer (score 2):

There is no single way to do this, as the definition of a project root is not built into emacs.

You can call:

- `ffip-project-root` for users of [find-file-in-project](https://github.com/redguardtoo/find-file-in-project).
- `projectile-project-root` for users of [projectile](https://projectile.mx/).

Without depending on 3rd party packages you can use `vc` directly (assuming projects use version control).

```el
(defun my-vc-root-path-or-default (filepath &optional default)
  "Return the version control directory from FILEPATH or DEFAULT."
  (let ((vc-base-path default))
    (condition-case err
      (let ((vc-backend (ignore-errors (vc-responsible-backend filepath))))
        (when vc-backend
          (setq vc-base-path (vc-call-backend vc-backend 'root filepath))))
      (error (message "Error creating vc-backend root name: %s" err)))
    vc-base-path))
```

Comment: I have no M-x projectile-project-root